# Animate a layout constraint constant from one value to another using Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uiviewanimation, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin studio and developing an iPad app with Xamarin.iOS.

I am setting a constant value against a layout constraint outlet in my c# file.

### What I have at the moment (no animations)

```
_myRightSpaceConstraint.Constant = 50;
```

### What I want

Animate this constant so that it goes from:

```
_myRightSpaceConstraint.Constant = 300;
```

to

```
_myRightSpaceConstraint.Constant = 50;
```

**OR**, similar to above but don't specifiy what the start constant is (300), instead I just take whatever it is set to in the xib file and animate to 50.

Is this possible to do this in Xamarin and if so are there any code examples to help me?

### What I have tried - which doesnt work

```
UIView.BeginAnimations ("slideAnimation");
float _pt;
_pt = _myRightSpaceConstraint.Constant;

UIView.SetAnimationDuration (5);
UIView.SetAnimationCurve (UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut);

UIView.SetAnimationDelegate (this);
UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector (
    new Selector ("slideAnimationFinished:"));

_myRightSpaceConstraint.Constant = 50;
UIView.CommitAnimations ();
```

This actually sets the constant successfully to 50 but with no animation.

### Edit/Update:

I managed to achieve what I wanted with the following:

```
_myRightSpaceConstraint.Constant = 150;
_myViewWithTheConstraint.SetNeedsUpdateConstraints ();

UIView.BeginAnimations ("slideAnimation");

UIView.SetAnimationDuration (1);
UIView.SetAnimationCurve (UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut);

UIView.SetAnimationDelegate (this);
UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector (
    new Selector ("slideAnimationFinished:"));

_myViewWithTheConstraint.LayoutIfNeeded ();

UIView.CommitAnimations ();
```

The following line was the key:

```
_myViewWithTheConstraint.LayoutIfNeeded ();
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted with the following:

```
_myRightSpaceConstraint.Constant = 150;
_myViewWithTheConstraint.SetNeedsUpdateConstraints ();

UIView.BeginAnimations ("slideAnimation");

UIView.SetAnimationDuration (1);
UIView.SetAnimationCurve (UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut);

UIView.SetAnimationDelegate (this);
UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector (
    new Selector ("slideAnimationFinished:"));

_myViewWithTheConstraint.LayoutIfNeeded ();

UIView.CommitAnimations ();
```

The following line was the key:

```
_myViewWithTheConstraint.LayoutIfNeeded ();
```

Comment: Can't remember. Who's Larry?

Comment: The person who answered this question above. You commented on his answer saying that it solved the problem but then you wrote your own answer and accepted that as the solution. Why didn't you accept the answer that was given to you?

Comment: @Cogwheel this was a while ago but from looking through this post it seems like Larry was hardcoding the constraints and values in the code. I wanted to update a constraint outlet alrady setup in the xib file. it didn't say his answer solved my problem, I commented that his mention of LayoutIfNeeded() helped me. I accepted mine as its the solution I ended up using.

Comment: In your answer you say "The following line was the key: _myViewWithTheConstraint.LayoutIfNeeded ()". That was exactly what Larry's answer said in the very first sentence. The code he provided was just an example. The general idea of calling LayoutIfNeeded is the real answer to this question, not whatever specific code you ended up with. You seem to be missing the forest for the trees here.

Answer (score 10):

Call `LayoutIfNeeded()` on the constrained views, as part of the `animations` action of `UIView.Animate`:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint[] dynConstraints;
    UIView redView;
    UIView greenView;

    public ContentView()
    {
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;

        redView = new UIView() {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red,
            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        };
        AddSubview(redView);

        greenView = new UIView(){
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green,
            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        };
        AddSubview(greenView);

        var viewsDictionary = new NSMutableDictionary();
        viewsDictionary["red"] = redView;
        viewsDictionary["green"] = greenView;

        dynConstraints= NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:|-[red]-100-[green(==red)]-|", 0, new NSDictionary(), viewsDictionary);
        AddConstraints(dynConstraints);
        AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:|-[red]-|", 0, new NSDictionary(), viewsDictionary));
        AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:|-[green(==red)]", 0, new NSDictionary(), viewsDictionary));

        this.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        foreach(var constraint in dynConstraints)
        {
            constraint.Constant = 50;
        }
        UIView.Animate(0.5, () => {
            redView.LayoutIfNeeded();
            greenView.LayoutIfNeeded();
        });
    }
```